# Latent Change Models: account for change in one latent variable as function of change in another

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, latent-variable, growth-model, lavaan

[Hertzog and Dixon (2003)](https://rpadgett.butler.edu/ps320/coursedocs/Hertzog03.pdf) 
specify that latent change models make it possible to predict change in one latent variable based on change in another. I would appreciate help conceptualizing how to create such a model with the data explained below. I intend to use the lavaan package in R.

The data I have comes from a single intervention (no control group). We collected data for 2 measures every week of the intervention, 12 weeks total. For a third measure, we collected data at pre, mid (6 weeks), post (12 weeks), 3 month followup (MFU), 6MFU, 9MFU, and 12MFU. I would like to investigate whether change in either of the first 2 latent variables account for change in the third latent variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set up two latent growth models with either a regression or a correlation between the latent slopes.

It's hard to know what to explain, as it's not clear how far you have got, but here's a path diagram: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/6341774_fig4_Figure-1-Bivariate-latent-growth-model-of-personality-and-relationships-Latent

Comment: Thank you, Jeremy. This is what I was looking for (i.e., a nudge in the right direction). I can post for others when the model is fully specified.